# i need to search Restuarants from google maps places via Intent?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

how to get restuarants near by my location via calling Intents ,how to do that i did google maps via intent like,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr="));
                startActivity(intent);
```

similar way is there any direct http link to to get restuarants.
help me any one..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [google places api](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearches) to search near by places like in your case restaurant around a particular location.